# jQuery find and replace with arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to search an input's value for all street abbreviations and replace with appropriate suffix. This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery('#colCenterAddress').val(function(i,val) {
    var f = ['Rd','St','Ave'];
    var r = ['Road','Street','Avenue'];
    return val.replace(f,r);
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: That works in PHP, but unfortunately not in JavaScript.

Comment: That is not a valid javascript invocation of replace. It's not particularly internationalisable. It's client side work, which is easily circumvented. You need to ensure that each match is preceded by whitespace and succeeded by a non word character.

Answer (score 14):

You need to iterate the `f` Array, and try each replace separately.

```
jQuery('#colCenterAddress').val(function(i,val) {
    var f = ['Rd','St','Ave'];
    var r = ['Road','Street','Avenue'];
    $.each(f,function(i,v) {
        val = val.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + v + '\\b', 'g'),r[i]);
    });
    return val;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vRTNt/

---

If this is something you're going to do on a regular basis, you may want to store the Arrays, and even make a third Array that has the pre-made regular expressions.

```
var f = ['Rd','St','Ave'];
var r = ['Road','Street','Avenue'];

var re = $.map(f, function(v,i) {
    return new RegExp('\\b' + v + '\\b', 'g');
});

jQuery('#colCenterAddress').val(function(i,val) {
    $.each(f,function(i,v) {
        val = val.replace(re[i],r[i]);
    });
    return val;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vRTNt/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var valArray = val.split(" ");

for(x = 0; x < valArray.length; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < r.length; y ++){
        if (valArray[x] == f[y]){
            valArray[x] = r[y];
        } 
     }
}
return valArray
```

You could always turn the array back into a string for the return if you like.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vRTNt/12/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, is to loop through the `val` string, and if you see a word in the `f` array, replace it with its counterpart in the `r` array.

```
jQuery('#colCenterAddress').val(function(i,val) {
    var f = ['Rd','St','Ave'];
    var r = ['Road','Street','Avenue'];
    var valArray = val.split(' ');
    $.each(valArray, function(i,v){
       var inF = $.inArray(v, f);
       if(inF !== -1){
         valArray[i] = v.replace(f[inF], r[inF]);
       }
    });
    return valArray.join(' ');
});
```