# How to loop Jquery variable option list

Tags: jquery

*Here is the original function** ----------------------------------------

```
function lang(t) {

        $(".OutLbl").each(function () {
             $(this).html(
               $(this).html()
                .replace("Search", diction.wordlist.Search[t])
                .replace("By", diction.wordlist.By[t])
                .replace("Select Language", diction.wordlist["Select Language"][t])
                .replace("ID", diction.wordlist["ID"][t])
              );
            });
    };

var diction = {
    wordlist: {
        "Search": {
            dh: "ހޯދާ",
            en: "Search"
        },
        "By": {
            dh: "އިން",
            en: "by"
        },
        "Select Language": {
            dh: "ބަސް ޙިޔާރުކުރޭ",
            en: "Select Language"
        },
        "ID": {
            dh: "އައިޑީ",
            en: "ID"
        },
    }
}
```

**I need to simplify the *replace* in the above function instead of multiple replaces by

looping for each option in diction[wordlist]options

some way like**

```
function lang(t) {
       $(diction[wordlist] options).each( function () {
       var lll = this;
              $(".OutLbl").each(function () {
                $(this).html(
                $(this).html().replace(lll, diction.wordlist[lll][t])
                );
            });
        });
    };
```

the question is how to loop all options of a variable (diction.wordlist in my case) in a function, as the one I tried above doesn't work.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? What's the question?

Comment: the question is how to loop all options of a variable (diction.wordlist in my case) in a function, as the one I tried above doesn't work.

Comment: Related/possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881436/jquery-find-and-replace-with-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var diction = {
    wordlist: {
        "Search": {
            dh: "ހޯދާ",
            en: "Search"
        },
        "By": {
            dh: "އިން",
            en: "by"
        },
        "Select Language": {
            dh: "ބަސް ޙިޔާރުކުރޭ",
            en: "Select Language"
        },
        "ID": {
            dh: "އައިޑީ",
            en: "ID"
        }
    }
};

function lang(t) {
    // initialise an array to store all the words/phrases:
    var words = [];
    // iterate over the properties of the 'diction.wordlist' object:
    for (var word in diction.wordlist) {
        // if the property is a property of the defined object:
        if (diction.wordlist.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
            // we push that word into the array:
            words.push(word);
        }
    }

    // creating a new RegExp, using the constructor, which allows us
    // to use variables. We create the literal regular expression:
    // /(Search)|(By)|(Select Language)|(ID)/
    // and use case-insensitivity (i) and global (g) flags:
    var reg = new RegExp('(' + words.join(')|(') + ')', 'gi');

    // using the html method and its anonymous function, which exposes:
    // i: the index of the current element amongst the collection, and
    // oldhtml: the current innerHTML of the current element (prior to manipulation)
    $('.OutLbl ').html(function (index, oldhtml) {
        // we return the html after replacing the matchedWords (using the callback
        // of replace():
        return oldhtml.replace(reg, function (matchedWord) {
            // finding the, for example, 'diction.wordlist['Search'][t]:
            return diction.wordlist[matchedWord][t];
        });
    });
}

$('#trigger').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    lang('dh');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SsTLJ/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
  - [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
  - [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
  - [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Well, I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `for...in` loop, sanitized with `hasOwnProperty` to avoid properties inherited through prototype:

```
$(".OutLbl").each(function () {
  var html = $(this).html();
  for(var word in diction.wordlist){
    if(diction.wordlist.hasOwnProperty(word))  {
      html = html.replace(word, diction.wordlist[word][t])
    }
  }
  $(this).html(html);
});
```

Note that, like your current code, it will replace only the first occurrence of each word.

To replace all of them, use regular expressions with `g` flag, escaping [necessary characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions).

```
var regExp = new RegExp(word.replace(/[.^$*+?()[{\|]/g, '\\$&'), "g");
html = html.replace(regExp, diction.wordlist[word][t])
```