# jQuery/Javascript solution for replacing multiple abbreviations

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

For example I need something that will parse a string and go through and replace multiple street types abbreviations with their full word ('Rd' would become 'Road'). This is  sort of answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881436/jquery-find-and-replace-with-arrays) but I would like something with a single object like below because this is going to be a pretty long list and this would help keep the correct organization,

```
var streets = {
       'RD': 'ROAD',
       'ST': 'STREET',
       'PL': 'PLACE'};
```

I know I've seen things like this before, but I'm kind of lost as to how to proceed from here. I know I need to take the string in question and run the value through this 'filter' (if you can call it that), but I'm just not sure how since I'm still pretty new to this. Thanks so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would just need a simple for/in loop to iterate through the keys and replace them in the string, something like this:

```js
var input = "something RD, other ST, some PL, another RD";
var streets = {
  'RD': 'ROAD',
  'ST': 'STREET',
  'PL': 'PLACE'
};

for (var key in streets) {
  var re = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
  input = input.replace(re, streets[key]);
}

console.log(input);
```

You could also change the regular expression logic to make the match more accurate if required; it would depend entirely on the format of your input string.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think that would definitely work. Could you expand on how that loop works with a breakdown, or should I open a new question?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The loop is iterating over the properties of the `streets` object. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This will give a problem if the keys are not mutually exclusive (one is substring of another). For example - if `RD` and `RDS` are the keys.

Comment: @gurvinder372 that's correct, which is why I noted about making the Regex more accurate if required.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed strings, use `.split().join()` like this

```
var streets = { 'RD': 'ROAD', 'ST': 'STREET', 'PL': 'PLACE'};
var str = 'Some ST that is by the PL along the RD where the ST is by that PL.'

for(k in streets){ str = str.split(k).join(streets[k]) }
```

Result

```
console.log(str)
Some STREET that is by the PLACE along the ROAD where the STREET is by that PLACE.
```